# Could not open input file: ./bin/phpbbcli.php when updating phpBB3.0 to phpBB3.1

Tags: upgrade, phpbb

I am trying to upgrade my phpBB forum from 3.0 to 3.1 (using the following guide: https://www.phpbb.com/support/docs/en/3.1/ug/upgradeguide/upgrade3/).

In step #9 I choose to use the command line, however upon typing the instruction I get the following error:

```
php ./bin/phpbbcli.php db:migrate --safe-mode
Could not open input file: ./bin/phpbbcli.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps some, who comes from search later on. 
This error means php can't find the file, because you're not executing the command from your forum's folder.
Either put the full path to phpbbcli.php or execute the command from the forum's folder.

Also you might need to specify which PHP to use, if you have more than one, especially if you see some SQL errors. You might be using the version not configured with mysql

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it, I was in the wrong folder. Once I navigated to the correct forum folder and ran the command again it worked as expected. Thank you for updating this question with your answer!